# Problems with XBT Tracker, a BitTorrent tracker 

Tags: bittorrent

I've been using [XBT Tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBT_Tracker) (a [BitTorrent tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker)). On [Debian Lenny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#2005.E2.80.93present) mostly. My problem is when the tracker reaches a given number of peers, it dies. There is no informative debug message, no dump, nothing. The last Windows release does mention a change which says it fixes this (I think that is the source of our problem), but since I run linux..

So.. What should I use? On which OS?

Comment: Can you add more info? What kind of hardware are you running, what kind of internet pipe do you have, about how many peers does it take to cause the issue? Also I would suggest adding what are you hosting on your tracker just so people don't down vote/vote to close the question assuming it's pirated software.

Comment: Its running on a 775 socket Intel (Core2 series). The load is not an issue, its way below any harmful level (about 0.3?). The network is about 1gbps at max output. The issue occurs about 850k/900k peers. Well.. I dont want to tell the site's name, but I use it to reduce networking costs to be honest. Not pirated software, not illegal stuff. But anyway, I dont want to reveal my identity (for the site's users). Yeah I know .. since I cant guarantee, its your choice to vote me down.. but.. please, help.

Comment: Use uTorrent on Windows.  Duh.

Comment: Uhm..as a tracker? :)

Comment: What's wrong with normal webbased trackers? These are more likely to be resilient to hardware failure and local power failure, as well as not sapping your internet connection. I also agree with you that bittorrent is a fantastic protocol that is unfortunately linked with pirated software and media.

Comment: Well..this is a simple web based tracker as you would call it. Uhm..yeah I know some open trackers are avaliable, but I don't really want to move there since every pirate started to use those. SADLY. Since large companies will shut them down again, and..yeah.. I'd be in a huge pinch then. Any idea about what other huge sites use?

Comment: Web-based trackers? You mean like tbsource, doing the announce as a PHP script? What's wrong with them is they're very inefficient: there is no way at all a PHP tracker can scale to 900k peers on any hardware. (You'll be lucky to get a tenth of that!)

Comment: Fuji: xbt is generally considered the best-performing tracker for private sites (there may be better for general-purpose open tracking). What's the change mentioned that you think addresses this on Windows builds? I can't see anything relevant in the 0.2.8 release notes.

Comment: Well, I found this in the changelog: Avoid tracker becoming unresponsive after descriptor limit has been hit. And sadly it beats me what is the problem. Tried to debug it, but no error msg, nothing at all. Nothing from the xbt debugger, nor from the console. ANY idea? :-/ (Should I use the latest SVN?.. last time that died about 350k peers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been using XBT Tracker (XBTT) on FreeBSD for quite a while. Now we have about 500k+ peers, and they are rapidly growing. And we have an announce interval of 700 second which is very low.

1. The only optimizations for XBT Tracker I've heard of in Linux are:

```
#Backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 4096
net.core.somaxconn = 4096

# In case you use listen_check
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 65535"

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

#Timewait sockets (this can negatively impact clients under NAT)
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1

#Firewall conntrack
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1048576
net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576
```

Do not forget to increase maximum number of opened files:

```
ulimit -n 1000000
```

and save changes to `limits.conf`

2. Our XBT Tracker uses following patch: [Listen Queue Len increase](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xbtt/forums/forum/328824/topic/3054115)

3. This configuration line can be helpful:

```
listen_check = 0
```

and also we have very short

```
read_files_interval = 2
write_db_interval = 3
```

4. MySQL tuning is required, as minimum you should increase

```
max_allowed_packet = 48M
```

5. Also as a side note, on Linux XBTT uses epoll(), while on other OSes it uses select() which is not suitable for highload.

PS. You can check out [OpenTracker](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/) if nothing helps. But I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Will try them out soon.... aaand.. sorry for the late reply. :)

Comment: Thanks Peter! Now it looks better. PS. Sorry English is not my native language as you can see =)